# Can't get inline images to work in Nextra static site

Tags: image, next.js, markdown, vercel, nextra

I'm trying to get images to appear inside a sentence in Nextra - such as: 'To close the window, click the Close [ICON].

I can achieve this result inside my IDE's preview window, but not inside my app. It also results in a line break before and after the image.

Can anyone advise on how this is done in Nextra? Absolute dealbreaker if it doesn't work!

P.S. I'm a tech author, not a dev!

https://nextra.site/docs

I tried standard markdown for images. Didn't work.